# rotate menu slide from right to left

Tags: html, css

how to rotate collapse menu slide from right to left?

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <style>
    #accordion {
      width: 55%;
      margin-left: 20px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    .panel {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .panel-heading {
      height: 40px;
    }
    .panel-title {
      height: 18px
    }
    .panel-title a {
      float: right;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 0px 10px;
      margin: 0px -10px;
    }
    .panel-body {
      height: 10%;
    }
    .cont {
      margin: 10px 00px;
    }
  </style>
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <TITLE>headerFrame.jsp</TITLE>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
<br>
  <div>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="cont">testing msesage</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

### expected

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code for vertical slide accordian. Here is the code

> working example : https://jsfiddle.net/yudi/qhnhnfjb/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="pink"></div>
      <div class="panelContent p1"> <strong>Section 1 Header</strong><br/>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In iaculis volutpat quam, non suscipit arcu accumsan at. Aliquam pellentesque.
      </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#accordion {
    list-style:none;
    margin:30px 0;
    padding:0;
    height:270px;
    width:980px;
    margin:0 0 0 11px;
    border-top:2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#accordion .panel {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    height:270px;
    width:44px;
    overflow:hidden;
    color:#666666;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:1.5em
}
#accordion .panel.active {
    width:848px
}
.panelContent {
    padding:15px 15px 15px 55px;
    height:240px;
    width:778px;
}
.pink {
    width:42px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background:url(../images/accordionSprite.png) no-repeat 4px 85px #f980a1;
    border-right:2px solid #ffffff;
    cursor:pointer
}
.last {
    border:none
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    activePanel = $("#accordion div.panel:first");
    $(activePanel).addClass('active');

    $("#accordion").delegate('.panel', 'click', function(e){
        if( ! $(this).is('.active') ){
            $(activePanel).animate({width: "44px"}, 300);
            $(this).animate({width: "848px"}, 300);
            $('#accordion .panel').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            activePanel = this;
         };
    });
});
```

Comment: i want it display from right to left.. and this output the menu bar cannot be collapse out when u click on single title.

Comment: didn't get u please elaborate your problem

Comment: hi, please check again the expected result, uploaded new image